# Mariadb database with more than 50 million rows

Tags: performance, mariadb

I recently designed a database to analyze data using the clickhouse database as an engine.

Everything works perfect and the performance of the database is very good considering that the server is more or less good and with almost 40 million records.

Up to this point everything is fine, but now I need to migrate to a mariadb database in order to use the data in conjunction with the glpi database.

I've been investigating and I can't find anything that answers the following questions:

1. Is mariadb able to handle this amount of data, knowing that over
   time we can reach more than **100 million**?
2. Using **mariadb galera cluster** could you get a better performance?

I appreciate any suggestions or options you can give me.

> I'm sorry if you don't understand something, my English is not very good.

Thank you so much.

Comment: The only real way to answer a question like "can X handle Y" is to build a sample of X and throw Y at it.

Comment: "It depends".  I have worked with 100M-row tables in MariaDB.  It can handle bigger tables.  Galera has advantages and disadvantages; its main advantage is "High Availability".